# How can I save an output in a variable?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
read -r path
wslpath -a $path
```

I want to save the output of wslpath in a variable so I can later use:

```
cd $converted_path
```

to change the directory.
How can I realize that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please remember to search for existing questions that are similar or the same as yours before posting a new one. This particular question has been asked many, many times, and most have been closed as duplicates of this one - [how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score -1):

The Bash syntax to capture output of a command is as such:

```
$MY_VAR=$(wslpath -a $path)
```

You can later use the variable:

```
cd $MY_VAR
```